# Nav anchor doesn't apply active class correctly while scroll jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website, it has a sticky nav placed at the bottom of a `<header>` element, as long as I scroll to a section it actives a class using `data-attributes` , the bug here is: when I scroll the class `active` adds on the half of the section even the scroll does not scroll according to the section.

What I want is to turn on the `active` class as long as I get the anchor of each section, I leave my code below followed by a jsfiddle you can see what is the problem, I hope you guys can help me.

The HTML:

```
<header class="testheader">

    <nav id="cloud_nav" class="absolute">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-scroll="overview">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-scroll="readiness">Section 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-scroll="collaboration">Section 3</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>

</header>    

<section data-anchor="overview" style="background: red; font-size: 25px;">

</section> 

<section data-anchor="readiness" style="background: green; font-size: 25px;">

</section>

<section data-anchor="collaboration" style="background: #ccc; font-size: 25px;">
</section>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // Sticky Nav

$('#cloud_nav a').on('click', function() {

    var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('data-scroll'),
        scrollPoint = $('section[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offset().top;

    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPoint
    }, 500);

    return false;

})

var navOffset = $('#cloud_nav').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){

    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();


    if (scrollPos >= navOffset){
        $('#cloud_nav').removeClass('absolute');
        $('#cloud_nav').addClass('fixed_cloud_nav');
       $('section').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).position().top <= scrollPos - 50) {
                $('#cloud_nav a.active').removeClass('active');
                $('#cloud_nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#cloud_nav').removeClass('fixed_cloud_nav');
        $('#cloud_nav').addClass('absolute');
        $('#cloud_nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#cloud_nav a:first').addClass('active');
    }
});
</script>
```

The Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qfaeqo2w/

Thanks in advance, regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were after?

http://jsfiddle.net/0ytvjtme/

First, I changed calculating the `scrollPoint` to take into account the size of the header:

```
scrollPoint = $('section[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offset().top - $('#cloud_nav').outerHeight();
```

Then, rather than *subtract* 50 pixels, we *add* the height of the nav where it's detecting the scroll position:

```
if ($(this).position().top <= scrollPos + $('#cloud_nav').outerHeight())
```

The anchors now scroll to the right place and the active classes look to be switched correctly.

Comment: Amazing!!, thanks for the comment, I've had spent too much time on this, thank you so much again!